# Repeating row values for 3-digit character sequence - tidy data

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-munging

Given the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(start = c("005", "010", "014"),
                   end = c("005", "013", "017"),
                  zone = c(3, 5, 7))
# df
#   start end zone
# 1   005 005    3
# 2   010 013    5
# 3   014 017    7
```

I would like to generate the following result:

```
#   key zone
# 1 005    3
# 2 010    5
# 3 011    5
# 4 012    5
# 5 013    5
# 6 014    7
# 7 015    7
# 8 016    7
# 9 017    7
```

I am thinking I might be able to leverage something from `tidyr` -- perhaps `complete()` or `expand()`, but having three-character strings for `df$start` and `df$end` has been giving me trouble.

I have been mildly successful using: `apply(df, 1, function(i) seq(as.numeric(i["start"]), as.numeric(i["end"])))` which I could then pass to something like `stringr::str_pad(..., width = 3, pad = "0")`, but I'm not sure how to grab the zones neatly for these repeated sequences.

Comment: Sorta hacky half-`dplyr`, but `apply(df, 1, function(x){data.frame(key = seq(as.numeric(x[1]), as.numeric(x[2])), zone = x[3])}) %>% do.call(rbind, .) %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(key = paste0(paste(rep('0', 3 - nchar(key)), collapse = ''), key))`

Comment: Thanks @alistaire, see my less-hacky `dplyr` approach -- might be something more straightforward, but I think the gist is there now. The `do()` statements always throw me off.

Answer (score 5):

Using `data.table` you can do this in three steps which are chained together. First, you convert the dataframe to a datatable with `setDT`. Second, you convert the `start` and `end` columns to numeric. Third, you create the `key` column by making sequences for each row in the original dataframe with the values from the `start` column as starting value and the values from the `end` column as end values. Fourth, you convert the `key` column back to character by using `sprintf` and add zero's in front of the numbers that are shorter than 3 digits:

```
library(data.table)
cols <- names(df)[1:2]
setDT(df)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))), .SDcols = cols
          ][, .(key = start:end), by = zone
            ][, key := sprintf('%03d',key)][]
```

which gives:

```
   zone key
1:    3 005
2:    5 010
3:    5 011
4:    5 012
5:    5 013
6:    7 014
7:    7 015
8:    7 016
9:    7 017
```

Depending on whether your `start` and `end` columns are character of factors, you should use either `as.numeric(x)` or `as.numeric(as.character(x))`.

Following the comment of @alistaire, you can curiously omit the `as.numeric` part. Thus:

```
setDT(df)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.character(x)), .SDcols = cols
          ][, .(key = start:end), by = zone
            ][, key := sprintf('%03d',key)][]
```

will give you the same result (when your `start` and `end` columns already character class, you can off course omit the `lapply` step).

Comment: can you add a bit of commentary to explain what's going on

Comment: `:` curiously handles characters (but not factors) fine, so you could probably simplify the `lapply`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another base R possibility ...

```
## Create the pairwise sequences after coercing factor columns to integer
x <- with(
    lapply(df[-3], function(x) as.integer(levels(x)[x])),
    Map(":", start, end)
)
## Use the sequences to create the new data frame
data.frame(key = sprintf("%03d", unlist(x)), zone = rep(df$zone, lengths(x)))
```

This leaves the original data unchanged and results in
the following.

> ```
>   key zone
> 1 005    3
> 2 010    5
> 3 011    5
> 4 012    5
> 5 013    5
> 6 014    7
> 7 015    7
> 8 016    7
> 9 017    7
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my `dplyr` approach, borrowing the idea from @ProcrastinatusMaximus:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(zone) %>%
  do(data.frame(key = .$start:.$end)) %>%
  mutate(key = sprintf('%03d', key))

#      zone   key
#     (dbl) (chr)
#   1     3   005
#   2     5   010
#   3     5   011
#   4     5   012
#   5     5   013
#   6     7   014
#   7     7   015
#   8     7   016
#   9     7   017
```

Answer (score 2):

A `dplyr`/`tidyr` option:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

      # make list column grouped by row
x %>% rowwise() %>% 
    # convert factors to character (if not already)
    mutate_each(funs(as.character), -zone) %>%
    # make key list column, drop unmentioned columns
    transmute(key = list(start:end), zone) %>% 
    # unnest list column
    unnest() %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    # add 0s
    mutate(key = paste0(paste(rep('0', 3 - nchar(key)), collapse = ''), key))

# Source: local data frame [9 x 2]
# Groups: <by row>
#     
#    zone   key
#   (dbl) (chr)
# 1     3   005
# 2     5   010
# 3     5   011
# 4     5   012
# 5     5   013
# 6     7   014
# 7     7   015
# 8     7   016
# 9     7   017
```

Comment: why not just `sprintf` instead of `paste0(paste(rep(... `?

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus Mostly because I've been too lazy to learn the formats (maybe it's time), though it's definitely simpler and could substitute nicely.

Comment: If you want to stay in the "hadleyverse" you could use `stringr::str_pad(..., width = 3, pad = "0")` I find this more intuitive (though more limited) than `sprintf` and less verbose than `paste0(paste(rep(`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution.

Following @alexis-las suggestion, I create a numeric matrix holding the start and end points, which reduces the computation in further steps.

```
# create numeric matrix for future calculations
timeMat <- sapply(df[, 1:2], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
# get the number of needed row repeats
rowRep <- timeMat[, 2] - timeMat[, 1] + 1
# get the keys
keys <- unlist(sapply(1:3, function(i) timeMat[i, 1]:timeMat[i, 2])

# get data.frame
data.frame("zone"=df$zone[rep(1:nrow(df), rowRep)], "keys"=sprintf("%03d", keys))

zone keys
1    3  005
2    5  010
3    5  011
4    5  012
5    5  013
6    7  014
7    7  015
8    7  016
9    7  017
```

---

The original method did not provide the zero padding for the keys, but instead returned the integers. Here is the lengthy function I constructed to build the padded 0s:

```
# add zero padding to keys
keys <- paste0(unlist(Map(function(x, y) paste(rep(x, each=y), collapse=""),
                                           rep("0", length(keys)), (3 - nchar(keys)))), keys)
```

Thanks to the comment of @alexis-laz pointing me to @procrastinatus-maximus's solution, this ugly function can be drastically simplified with `sprintf` as

```
# add zero padding to keys
keys <- sprintf("%03d", keys)
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something a similar simpification might be `mat = sapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))); dif = mat[, 2] - mat[, 1] + 1; data.frame(key = sprintf("%.03d", rep(mat[, 1], dif) + sequence(dif) - 1), zone = rep(mat[, 3], dif))` to, also, avoid converting `df[c("start", "end")]` to "numeric" more than once and reduce the amount of computations inside `sapply`

Comment: @alexis_laz Thanks for taking a look and showing a cleaner method. This code does simplify things, though I'll have to spend some time with `sequence` and the `sprintf` formats.